# CakePHP schema when using Translate behavior

Tags: cakephp, internationalization

I use `TranslateBehavior` with two fields:

- name
- slug

I drop these fields from Model, because content for fields will be saved in `i18n table`. It works perfectly, but sometimes in my app I use `$this->Model->hasField('name')` and after when I drop fields from Model table, this function always returns false. Is there some solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Virtual Fields

The translate behavior uses [virtual fields](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html), as such if you query for `hasField` for a field that does *not* exist - it will rightly return false, because the field does not physically exist.

### hasField + Translate behavior will never "work"

The translate behavior creates virtual field definitions on demand before a query, and destroys them after a query. as such you can't just use [the second parameter of hasField](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html#model-hasfield) as unless you manage to call it inbetween the [beforeFind](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Model/Behavior/TranslateBehavior.php#L93) and [afterFind](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Model/Behavior/TranslateBehavior.php#L269) methods of the translate behavior the result will always be false:

```
$willAlwaysBeFalse = $this->hasField('name', true);
```

### Alternatives

There are a few things you can do take your pick:

- Override hasField so that it returns true for these almost-virtual translated fields
- Define a dummy virtual field for the translated fields so that the second arg of `hasField` does permit you to get a positive response
- Don't delete the un-used translated field - so `hasField` always returns true

The Simplest solution is to not delete the field. This will also ensure that, while the data may be blank, your models still work if the translate behavior is disabled or some kind of error exists.

Comment: Unfortunately, it still does not work. In model I use Translate with array with slug field, thats all.

Comment: Now, the answer is full:) I older project I use $this->Model->Behaviors->Translate to check of fields, but the better is no delete fields.